# Cardinality/Countably Infinite

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

x -(ℕ) is called a power of five if there exists another natural number, y, such that $5^y$=x. How can i proove that the set of powers of five is countably infinite?
I am at a loss to understand the bijective/surjective/injective functions and how i would use them to proove this.

Comment: Have you seen examples of some other sets , and how they are shown to be countably infinite? What examples have you seen? Because this is a fairly basic example, one that needs to be done by definition of countability.

Answer (score 1):

The map $$y\rightarrow 5^y$$ where $\ y\ $ runs over the positive integers, is a bijective map from the positive integers to the powers of $\ 5\ $ , if we do not consider $\ 1\ $ to be a power of $\ 5\ $

Since the set of positive integers is infinite countable , the set of powers of $\ 5\ $ must be infinite countable as well.

If you consider $\ 1\ $ to be a power of $\ 5\ $, the same argument works , when $\ y\ $ runs over the non-negative integers.